# Iframe и много вопросов

Tags: mobile-web, html, html5, iframe

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Есть у меня маленькое приложение для мобилки, сделанное на html5. С помощью линков сделал загрузку картинок со своего сайта, а текстовый контент (news.txt) через iframe в классическом исполнении. Все грузится и отображается, но если, допустим, вырубить инет, то на этом месте, где находится iframe, появляется надпись "Веб-страница недоступна, бла-бла..." и ссылка на мой сайт.

Вот каким мне способом можно скрыть все это безобразие, к примеру, чтобы на этом месте отображалось типа "Потеряна связь с сервером, нажмите обновить"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забудьте про `iframe` и грузите данные с помощью AJAX. Это даст вам гораздо больше контроля над процессом загрузки. В частности, позволит отображать любую заглушку при потере свзяи с сервером. К тому же, вы сможете загружать чистые данные (JSON), а форматировать их уже на клиенте в зависимости от потребностей (responsive design).

Comment: Один уважаемый помог уже. Скрипт элементарный.

<iframe id='test' src="news_ru.txt" width="200" height="400"> </iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#test") .error(function() { alert( "Handler for .error() called.") }) .attr("src", "news_ru2.txt");
</script>